# PhotoViewController + MockPhotoSource (display local photos)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

If someone have ever use the PhotoViewController and so the MockPhotoSource in the three20 open source project can he told me how can I change the code to display photo store locally and not in the internet.
This is an example of the code to display one photo:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.photoSource = [[MockPhotoSource alloc]
                        initWithType:MockPhotoSourceNormal
                        title:@"Flickr Photos"
                        photos:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
[[[MockPhoto alloc]
initWithURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3246/2957580101_33c799fc09_o.jpg"  
smallURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3246/2957580101_d63ef56b15_t.jpg"                               
size:CGSizeMake(960, 1280)] autorelease], nil]
 ];
}
@end
```

The method look like that:

```
- (id)initWithURL:(NSString )URL smallURL:(NSString)smallURL size:(CGSize)size
    caption:(NSString*)caption {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    _photoSource = nil;
    _URL = [URL copy];
    _smallURL = [smallURL copy];
    _thumbURL = [smallURL copy];
    _size = size;
    _caption = [caption copy];
    _index = NSIntegerMax;
  }
  return self;
}
```

I'm not an expert in objective-C and there is not enough help for this project for the moment I think.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I find a solution, it was not complicated I just need to use the bundle path just after initWithURL and smallURL like that:

```
initWithURL:(@"bundle://image.jpg")
smallURL:(@"bundle://smallimage.jpg")
```

Of course after I will use a database to display the path so I will put an argument after bundle I think its '%s'

Answer (score 1):

URL is not only for the resource on the internet, there's a [file URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). Typically, you generate a file URL in Cocoa as in

> NSString* path= some path in the file system ;
>   NSURL* fileURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

Then you can use the fileURL as you want!

Comment: I'm not really understand.
I was trying to change initWithURL:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3246/2957580101_33c799fc09_o.jpg" by this initWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"...." ofType:@"..."] but its not finding anything

Comment: `-[NSBundle pathForResource: ofType:]` returns an `NSString`. Didn't you see a compiler warning? You need to further wrap it by `-[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`.

Comment: no compiler wrning because as you can see before in my code the URL is define to be a string.